# Best Approach to support dynamic database

Tags: java, database, postgresql, database-design

My project has a requirement to support configurable forms format. What I mean by that is the user can add 'n' number of columns to a form(to design it) and then the column data has to be saved in the db. Later on I also want to query on those columns for where clause..

But since the number and type of columns is not fixed, how do I design my database to support such a functionality?? I am using Java as my programming language and PostgreSQL db.

Comment: What University are you going to - we just had a very similar question.

Comment: @dngfng not university question dude, its my office project requirement.. :P

Comment: how do we get this question every damn week?

Comment: Because customers keep asking that question to newbee fresh-from-school programmmers every week.  It's the customers who keep hoping that there IS a silver bullet, and that this fresh-from-school-kid they've never seen before knows how to fire it.  And because none of the people involved can accept "no" for an answer.

Comment: It's been over a week.  Are you going to accept an answer or give us more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not as hard as it sounds.  You just need a separate table for the columns in the form and for the value in each entity (one instance of the filled in form).  This is sometimes call and [Entity Attribute Value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model).

form

- ID
- Name
- etc

form_column

- Form ID
- column
- attribute

entity

- ID
- form ID

entity_attribute

- entity ID
- form column
- attribute
- value (you can just use string, or have a value_string, value_int, and value_float)

To search for entities, your query screen can build up the SELECT statement by adding "OR (entity_attribute.entity_id=entity.entity_id and entity_attribute.attribute=FOO and entity_attribute.value=BAR)" subclauses to the WHERE clause.

An alternate approach would be to store the form design and the entities (filled in forms) as XML.  From there you can use XMLBeans or a DOM parser to work with the entities.

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate table that will contain column values:

```
-------------------------------
| formId | columnNo | value   |
-------------------------------
| 1      | 1        | first   |
-------------------------------
| 1      | 2        | second  |
-------------------------------
| 1      | 3        | third   |
-------------------------------
```

Column numbers can be alternatively changed to column names. Of course there should be another table where you keep how many columns each form has.
This is the easiest solution. Things get more complicated when you need different data types for different columns.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build exactly the same kind of solution as the person called 'Randy' did in

http://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/

You can also google for 'inner platform effect', because if you try to build something that matches up to that requirement, then that's exactly what you will be doing.

You will just be re-creating a DBMS outside your existing DBMS.  You will be re-creating type and domain checks in your application code, while your existing DBMS already has them, and for exactly the same purpose as what the DBMS already offers for free.  You will be re-creating expression parsers and compilers, while your existing DBMS already has them.  You will be re-creating selections of data access strategies, while your existing DBMS already has them.  And every little thing you will be re-creating and that your existing DBMS already has, will be a much poorer version of what your existing DBMS already has.

Your user is seeking a software solution that can be built right now, and that can and will suit all possible needs he might run into in the future, without the further intervention of an IT person (meaning : where your user takes on the role of database designer, while not having the skills to do that, and while hoping that your app will fill in all the knowledge gaps that is needed, but not had by the user, to play that role).

Does that sound to you like a reasonable requirement ?  Do you really think that it is even remotely possible to build such an application ?  Well, it is possible, kind of.  Such applications do exist.  They are called DB2, Oracle, Sybase, PostgreSQL, ...  I have little doubt that it will be beyond reach for you to build something that matches those in a timeframe that your user can be kept waiting.